# Typescript: Type Filtering by Property of Interface matched with Value of itself

Tags: typescript, generics

Want to make filtered type from first argument for second argument

Please check the below codes:

```js
interface TypeWithLabel {
    label: string;
    list: string;
}

interface A extends TypeWithLabel{
    label: 'a';
    list: '1' | '2' | '3';
}

interface B extends TypeWithLabel {
    label: 'b';
    list: '4' | '5' | '6';
}

type TypeProperty<T, U extends keyof T> = T[U];

function ab<T extends TypeWithLabel, U = TypeProperty<T, 'label'>>(
    label: U,
    item: TypeProperty<T, 'list'>
) {

}

// want to get A Only with label:'a'
// then display '1' | '2' | '3' for item
ab<A | B>('a', '1'); // correct
ab<A | B>('a', '4'); // error

// want to get B Only with label:'b'
// then display '4' | '5' | '6' for item
ab<A | B>('b', '4'); // correct
ab<A | B>('b', '1'); // error
```

Perhaps, is there another way to filtering the interfaces?
I thought about how to reuse generics, but `label` is required in function as string value.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if I understood you correctly - if you want function `ab` to be scoped to either `A` or `B`, then your generic type parameter should reflect this requirement as well. You'll want to change you code to:

```
// given A, restrict item to '1' | '2' | '3'
ab<A>("a", "1"); // ok
ab<A>("a", "4"); // error (ok)

// given A, restrict item to '4' | '5' | '6'
ab<B>("b", "4"); // ok
ab<B>("b", "1"); // error (ok)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOEDqwwAWAMnAEYQA2yA3gFDLIVmUBcyAzmFKAOYDc9RsE5tO3EP1oBfWrVCRYiFAEFkEAB6QQAE3ZosufMWZU6DJuQpsARHGsDzwsDYCM15AB9k1gEzuv1gDM9tKy8tDwSMgAQmqaEDp6GNh4hCSWNIIWrN6kIY4i3gAs-t4ArKXWAGwhMrRgBvrYAApQAPbYUA0APKgANMgAqnFausgA1hDobTBoAHzIALxoANqDALoCtDAAriAIYMBtIMhkvSMJY8mGaSYDw8vXrR3QPf3e2RTWc3MAFFkmNiDPqCfAQAC2bCe7U6bwG1goTm+tAAlDQ6gB6DHIADucHAyDAbWQPAgYGQqgA8iAKOhcUZGICAORwJm0LGEggJZDaYSYJh0pkuJmeZBMnwirxMwIimBtKDIMHg2hnZR-WzWeFuFF8ZAchDyqAQA4q0jdNW-DXwko6vXY6DtKCyDl4glEklkmLIam0+mERmWFhM0hsjmEbm89j8uCCoqSsVleNMqqy+WKyDKs7RdV5a3WW36w3GsCm7rZy257za3Uch3y2hAA)

Above code has the slight disadvantage, that the generic type parameter has to be set manually. If one day `U = TypeProperty<T, 'label'>` cannot provide a default type anymore, `U` has to be added as well in every code place involving `ab` and cannot be inferred.

An alternative is to create a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) `LabelToList`. This style is advantageous, if you only have a couple interfaces like `A` and `B` and many `ab` invocations. You can omit the manual generic type parameters by coding your example like this:

```
type LabelToList = {
  a: A;
  b: B;
};

function ab<K extends keyof LabelToList>(
  label: K,
  item: LabelToList[K]["list"]
) {}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOEDqwwAWAMnAEYQA2yA3gFDLIVmUBcyAzmFKAOYDc9RsE5tO3EP1oBfWrVCRYiFAEFkEAB6QQAE3ZosufMWZU6DJuQpsARHGsDzwsDYCM15AB9k1gEzuv1gDM9tKy8tDwSMgAQmqaEDp6GNh4hCSWNIIWrN6kIY4i3gAs-t4ArKXWAGwhMrRgBvrYAApQAPbYUA0APKgANMgAqnFausgA1hDobTBoAHzIALxoANqDALoC9Y3plKhtRE5LmQxwbMoOyKRs0QJSWzAAriAIYMBtIMhk3QDSIwljSbTWa7Cj7Q6cOYACiyJjYPz6gnwEAAtmxQeCnCsfusVtYKE5rOtaABKGh1AD0FOQAHc4OBkGA2sgeBAwMhVAB5EAUdC0oyMOEAcjgQtoVMZBASyG0wkwTD5QpcQs8yCFPhVXiFgRVMDaUGQyJRtDIUNs1gG1jcJL4yAlCH1UAgrxNpDNdktJRtdup0HaUFkErpDKZLLZMWQ3N5-MIgssLCFpDFEsI0tl7HlcEVRU1arKuaFVV1+sNkGNpuseU91m99sdzrArrNVe81ttEr9+toQA)